# Evaluate the double integral

Tags: integration

I have to solve this double integral, but it's just enough for me to know the correct limits to integration:

$$\iint_D (y^2 \sqrt{x} )  \,dx\,dy$$

Conditions: $x > 0, y > x^2 $ and $y < 10 - x^2 $

I have two functions, $y_1(x) = x^2$ and $y_2 (x) = 10 - x^2$
They have two points in common : $p_1 = (-\sqrt{5},5) $ and $p_2 (\sqrt{5},5) $, but as it's $ x > 0 $ we only take care of $p_2$.

So my idea is that my integral should look like this:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{5}} \int_{x^2}^{10 - x^2}{y^2\sqrt{x}} \,dx\,dy $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your "limits" are correct.

Comment: The order of integration matters when you introduce the integral bounds.  You should exchange $dx$ and $dy$. This is because, once the integral $\int \cdot dx$ is computed, you should no longer have any $x$ dependence. However, you would be adding the $x$ back in by plugging in the bounds.

Comment: Thus you should write $\int_0^\sqrt{5} \int_{x^2}^{10-x^2} y^2 \sqrt{x} dy dx$.